# terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows should be an object - vscode 1.63

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode 1.63 I'm seeing the error

`Incorrect type. Expected "object".`

for `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PS7"`

even though [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) appear to show its a string

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "PS7": {
                "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
                "args": [
                    "-noexit",
                    "-file",
                    "${env:APPDATA}PowerShellmy-init-script.ps1"
                ]
            },
            "PowerShell": {
                "source": "PowerShell",
                "icon": "terminal-powershell"
            },
            "Command Prompt": {
                "path": [
                    "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                    "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
                ],
                "icon": "terminal-cmd"
            },
            "GitBash": {
                "path": [
                    "F:\\Program files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
                ],
                "icon": "terminal-bash"
            },
            "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PS7"
        },
```

Comment: It appears you have that `defaultProfile` inside the `profiles` setting - move it outside to its own line.  And I assume all your settings are wrapped in `{ ...}` to make the whole thing an object - like in your link to the docs.

Comment: After that are you sure that the Powershell 7 path was added to the PATH environment variable?  You should have `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;` in there.  `echo $PATH` - if it isn't in there I think would conclude that `PS7` is not a legal entry.

Comment: This resolved my issue, many thanks